# Fatal error: "isEven" is an invalid render array key /web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php

Tags: theming

we have this code in template.theme but when we go to view the web, the page show a error as this: "isEven" is an invalid render array key /web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php . I dont understand very good Drupal and as works it.

```
function fcjc_bootstrap_preprocess_paragraph(&$variables)
{
  /** @var \Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph $paragraph */
  $paragraph = $variables['paragraph'];
  if ($paragraph->getType() === 'image_text_full_width' || $paragraph->getType() === 'imaxe_texto_biografia_') {
    $variables['isEven'] = $variables['elements']['isEven'];
  }
}


function fcjc_bootstrap_preprocess_field__field_image_text_section(&$vars)
{
  foreach ($vars['items'] as $delta => &$item) {
    $classname = ($delta % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd');
    $item['attributes']->setAttribute('class', $classname);
    $item['content']['isEven'] = ($delta % 2 == 0);
    }
}
```

In paragraph.twig I have this:
`<div class=" image col-sm-4 col-xs-12 {% if isEven %}right-shadow{% else %}left-shadow col-sm-push-8{% endif %}">`

Can Somebody can help me? please. Thx

Comment: It's probably this line `$item['content']['isEven'] = ($delta % 2 == 0);` you're adding something into the $item['content'] render array which isn't renderable

Comment: It's a paragraph with diferent  content. Inside this parapraph there are image and text block.
With this code we want to add differents classes if is even or odd to all paragraphs in template.twig when page is loaded.

Comment: Are you intentionally overwriting `$item['content']['isEven']` with a single value? If so, it might be better to define `isEven` as a property, so that it is written as `$item['content']['#isEven']`. You can add any arbitrary properties to a render array.

Answer (score 0):

It's what @Beau wrote in the comment. You have to put a ***#*** in the array key.

The code should be:

```
function fcjc_bootstrap_preprocess_paragraph(&$variables)
{
  /** @var \Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph $paragraph */
  $paragraph = $variables['paragraph'];
  if ($paragraph->getType() === 'image_text_full_width' || $paragraph->getType() === 'imaxe_texto_biografia_') {
    $variables['isEven'] = $variables['elements']['#isEven'];
  }
}


function fcjc_bootstrap_preprocess_field__field_image_text_section(&$vars)
{
  foreach ($vars['items'] as $delta => &$item) {
    $classname = ($delta % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd');
    $item['attributes']->setAttribute('class', $classname);
    $item['content']['#isEven'] = ($delta % 2 == 0);
    }
}
```